# Laravel query and array

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

please help me. I want to ask:

Let say I have 2 tables: `user_master` and `people`.

Now I am currently build an application in PHP with Laravel 5.1 framework that select the data from `user_master` table (with some constraint in `where` clause) and insert into `people` table.

The code is :

```
public function handle() {
   $results = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT * FROM user_master WHERE div_id = 1"));

   foreach ($results as $res) {
        //saving to array
        //insert query to table people here.
    }
}
```

My questions are:

1. How to save the result of `select` query to array, and
2. Insert that array into `people` table using **RAW** query (`INSERT INTO people VALUES (...)`).

*P.S.*: My query is **RAW** query, **not** using Eloquent. And please provide answer without Eloquent.

Thank you so much for any answer.

Comment: Any specific reasons behind using RAW queries. 1) Need to use `->get();`  method to get result within your `$result` variables

Comment: you can use array_push() to make an array of your foreach loop

Comment: @lewis4u: can you give me some example??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done the same scenario like this

```
$users=DB::table('Users')->where('created_at' ,'>=','2016-09-06')->get();
        foreach ($users as $user){
            DB::table('users_report')->insert(
                array(
                    'id' => $user->id,
                    'username' => $user->username,
                    'lastname' => $user->lastname,
                    'email' => $user->email,
                    'created_at' => $user->created_at,
                    'updated_at' => $user->updated_at,
                    )
            );
        }
```

change your like according to your logic , its works 100% perfectly..

Comment: this is the answer I'm looking for. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

if your table and master have the same strucure, you just set the  primary key in the below code. If they are not in the same structure, you have to ajust the results to the structure of the people bfore you insert to peopel table.

hope it will helps.

```
function delete_col(&$array, $offset) {
    return array_walk($array, function (&$v) use ($offset) {
        unset($v[$offset]);
    });
}
   public function handle() {
$results = DB::table('user_master')->where('div_id', 1)->get();
delete_col($results, $premiarykeyOfuser_master);

    DB::table('people')->insert($results);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that is right

```
$results = DB::table('user_master')->where('div_id', 1)->get();
```